# If you play more than one music track at once on a computer, does the sound heard get louder?

Tags: soft-question, acoustics

Say you are using a computer and have multiple Youtube videos playing music (or any other video) at the same time, does the **sound produced** by the computer's speakers (or a pair of headphones) **become louder** than just playing one video?
I.e. does the **amplitude** of the sound waves from multiple videos get added together, or does the amplitude (and therefore the volume heard) remain the same and only the **number of frequencies** that are heard increase?

Comment: In a lot of ways this is a technology question rather than a physics one. Some might argue that because the sound system is designed correctly you can treat it as two physical sounds sources and analyze it on that basis, but the reliance on design doesn't make me (personally) happy.

Comment: AFAIK the volume of the speakers is fixed. So whatever we play the net loudness of the output is fixed. There can be two ways multiple songs are played by the computer, 1. It decodes the digital data of all the songs and adds aup all the analog counterparts, 2. It playes songs at small descrete intervals, e.g. first song  for 1ms then 2nd for 1ms then back first for 1ms and then second for 1ms and so on.

Comment: The better question could be how the ears distinguish different songs as the net sound recieved is an interfrence of two sound waves. Or more precisely if one song is simply a wave say $\sin wt$ and another is $\sin(180+wt)$, would the ear hear both of em or nothing at all?

Comment: @dmckee I agree with you. In my answer I have tried to distinguish between the physics and the electronics. Does it make sense?

Comment: A quick check is: Play 10 songs simultaneously. Does the sound become 10 times as before? Obviously not.

Comment: @user31782 It certainly would not do the second - that's how the CPU works and it makes each individual program slower when that happens. More to the point, you would not get the sound that you get if that were the case - have you ever tried holding down the play/pause key whilst music is playing in a media player? (Usually the space bar.) That would make it sound juddery, and there'd be a _click_ sound every time it transitioned between different tracks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Assuming that you have two **independent** and **uncorrelated** sound sources, then the intensity observed will be the sum of the intensity of the two sources. Whether they were summed electronically before being turned into sound, or whether they were generated as separate sound waves that are summed when they reach your ear, is irrelevant.

Whether that happens in a particular instance of a particular computer and implementation of sound cards is something outside of the scope of physics. Some systems have sound equalization mechanisms that will interfere with the laws of physics...

Let me give a simple example. Assume that one sound is a sine wave with a frequency of 1.0 kHz and an amplitude of 1.0 (units), and another sound is a sine wave with a frequency of 2.0 kHz with an amplitude of 0.5 (units). If you add the amplitudes of these two signals together, you get the following:

[image]

Now the *intensity* of a sound is the time-averaged integral of the square of the amplitudes.

If you have the individual signals $S_1 = A_1 \sin(\omega_1 t)$ and $S_2=A_2\sin(\omega_2 t)$, their intensities are

$$\begin{align}I_1 &= \frac{\int_0^T \left(A_1 \sin(\omega_1 t)\right)^2 dt}{T}\\
&= \frac12 A_1^2
\end{align}$$

when $T$ is a (half-)integer multiple of the period of the signal. In the same way, we find $I_2 = \frac12 A_2^2$, and $I_{1+2} = \frac12\left(A_1^2+A_2^2\right)$ which is the same as the sum of the intensity of the individual signals.

This does rely on there being no *distortion* in the sound channel: for example, the signal must not *clip* (if the electrical amplitude exceeds the capability of the amplifier, the output wave form will look like it had its top "cut off" and the energy in the sound will be lowerere), and it must not *compress* (some amplifiers have a mechanism for maintaining constant loudness of signal by measuring the intensity, and "dialing back" the gain if the signal gets too loud. This can be helpful to stop the "shouting" of car adverts in the middle of an otherwise quiet movie, but would mess with the physics described here).

Comment: This is correct as long as you don't allow the net amplitude to be clipped by the limits of the sound system at any time. But I fear it is so terse as to only be comprehensible to people who could have deduced it for themselves.

Comment: @dmckee - fair point. I will expand...

Comment: A question has been in my mind for a long time. How does our ear understand the interfered sound from multiple sources? E.g. if two men shout simultaneously our ear could tell that two persons are shouting.

Comment: @user31782 That's essentially a physiology or cognitive question with a small but important amount of physics input in the form of noticing that the cochlea detects the frequency-space power components of the signal (i.e. it detects the Fourier transform of the time-dependent pressure function).

Comment: @dmckee - there is also a significant phase (or lag) detection component involved in the processing of multiple sounds... we can "tune" to sound from a particular direction by selecting for the difference in arrival time between left and right ear.

Comment: Nice expansion.